# Team Coherence with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2010

For source control we currently use Team Coherence 7.1.3.25, which has been working great under a few different editions of Visual Studio, the latest being VS2008. We are migrating to VS2010 and I am not sure how to get TC to work with it. Do we need to make the switch to TFS, or is there an option to get TC to work with VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the answer:
"Make sure that you check the 'SCC API' support option in the IDE Installation tool (IDEInst.exe in the installation folder).

When you next run VS, you should then have the 'Source Control' option under the File menu.

If you need more information, let me know.

Regards

Ewan McNab
Quality Software Components Ltd
Version Control with Team Coherence"